# ¿Como poner registros en una sola fila mediante un ID en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada act, en esta tabla tengo varios campos 20 en total, pero por algun motivo se guardan la información de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir en un formulario al enviar los datos a la BD se llena el campo question1_a1s1, despues en otro formulario se llena el campo question1_a1s2, pero este se llena debajo del primer registro.

Quiero realizar una consulta donde me traiga en una sola fila estos registros, es decir así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente con un max de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT id_u_a, id_user, question1_a1s1,
MAX(question1_a1s2) AS question1_a1s2
FROM act
```

Recibo lo que quiero, pero mi pregunta es que si se puede optimizar esta consulta ya que como comento, son 20 campos y se guarda la información una de bajo de la otra, entonces la consulta seria muy larga. Los campos pueden aumentar en 50, 100.

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar, la consulta que muestras funciona de casualidad, porque coincide que se ha introducido el registro de `question1_a1s1` antes que el siguiente y únicamente tienes un usuario en la tabla.

Suponiendo que todos los campos del formulario sean booleanos, esta otra consulta podría hacer lo que buscas y para más de un usuario:

```
SELECT id_user, 
  SUM(IFNULL(question1_a1s1,0)) question1_a1s1,
  SUM(IFNULL(question1_a1s2,0)) question1_a1s2
  FROM act
  GROUP BY 1;
```

Pero igualmente tendrías que duplicar la línea del `SUM` veinte veces.

Lo más sencillo sería modificar cómo registras cada respuesta desde el script que recibe los datos del formulario o, si eso no es posible y los campos no son todos booleanos, entonces arreglarlo con un disparador que lo vaya colocando todo en el mismo registro.